# Building an SDK like Facebook and setting application id and secret

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question. I am building an SDK for a website like Facebook.

I want people to set their applicationId and secret before they make calls using the SDK.

I do the following

```
[SDK setApplicationId: XXX and secret: XXX]
```

How can I then be able to access that id and secret from the other classes if there are being stored as static variables in the SDK class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare a static variable in `SDK.m` (or whatever) like this:

```
static NSString* appId;
static NSString* appSecret;
```

Than, in the implementation of `SDK` (don't forget to declare these in the header!):

```
+(void)setApplicationId:(NSString*)aid secret:(NSString*)sec {
  appId = aid;
  appSecret = sec;
}
+(NSString*)getAppId {
  return appId;
}
+(NSString*)getAppSecret {
  return appSecret;
}
```

Then, in any other file, just import `SDK.h`, and call `[SDK getAppId]` and `[SDK getAppSecret]`.